# Azure PaaS communicating with Azure Storage - use SSL or not?

Tags: security, azure, azure-storage

I have a web role that talks to Azure Storage, Azure Shared Cache Service and Azure SQL Databases. It is only ever the web roles that communicate with these storage mediums, and never the client browser. The Azure Table Storage contains sensitive data, but the cache and SQL databases do not.

Question is, if all data access goes over plain HTTP, is there a risk that someone can intercept my packets, and read my storage key? If so, who can sniff these packets - just Microsoft employees, or do I need to worry about other Azure tenants that might have effected a jailbreak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- If your webrole and storage accounts are in the same data center, then the traffic is contained within data center. In that case, going of HTTP would not create any problems IMO. However if the webrole and storage accounts are in different data centers, then definitely make use of HTTPS.
- Since you never send your storage account key with your requests to storage, you can be assured on that part. What you do is sign the requests using your key (or the storage client library does) and send that signature as a part of your requests. I don't think one would be able to reverse engineer that signature to get your storage account key.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, you should also take a look at the official security whitepaper: [Windows Azure Security Overview](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/2/6028B1AE-4AEE-46CE-9187-641DA97FC1EE/Windows%20Azure%20Security%20Overview%20v1.01.pdf). It talks about how isolation and packet filter secure the communication in the datacenter.